# Stream camera live preview from Android phone to PC

Tags: android, streaming

How can I stream camera preview from Android phone to PC through Wifi or USB connection?
Currently there are 2 potential projects, spydroid-ipcamera and ipcamera-for-android, both on Google code. However, their video stream is laggy and quality is very low. Is there any other solution?